# Can Twilio API send sms to customer which is replied by oweners personal phone number

Tags: php, sms-gateway, twilio

Suppose i have a twilio number (#AAA), if customer 'C' sends a sms to my twilio number(#AAA) from his number (#DDD). Then my sms app forward this sms to my personal phone number(#BBB) from twilio number(#AAA). Now if i reply this sms, then it send sms to my twilio number(#AAA). now is it possible to identify that my app now send this reply sms to customer number(#DDD).

Also think there are 2 customer 'Alex' and 'tasid'. All sms are forwarded to my personal number, now if i reply both sms then it will go to my twilio number(#AAA), now is there any way to detect which one is the reply sms for alex and which on is for tasid.

is there any other way to do it. Any Idea!!!

Comment: You could try buying multiple numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Tasiddiqul,

The simplest way to solve this would be to store a little bit of information in cookies:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/your_response#cookies

From the docs:

> Twilio will keep cookie state across multiple SMS messages between the
>   same two phone numbers. This allows you to treat the separate messages
>   as a conversation, and store data about the conversation, such as a
>   session identifier, in the cookies for future reference. Twilio will
>   expire the cookies for that conversation after four hours of
>   inactivity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Carter, You were missing my point. You will reply all sms to same twilio number then how your application differentiate the reply messages.The coockie value will be same for #AAA and #BBB. Let me be more clear. You sms to #AAA, our Application forward it to my phone #BBB, i will reply it and it will go to my twilio number #AAA, now my application need to send this replied sms to your number #DDD. Also think another person do the same thing and i have also relied him. Now look both replied sms will goes first my twilio number then my application will send sms to them by recognize replied sms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that IF you (a) track the incoming messages (and sender's phone number) in a database, and (b) include the sender's phone number when you forward the message to yourself and (c) when you reply, START the reply with the sender's phone number. So when YOU send a reply, your app forwards it to the phone number at the start of your message.

```
you receive:
from 1234567: Hi Joe how are you doing?

you send:
1234567 I'm doing fine thanks how about you?
```